# How should I capture clickstream data?

Tags: client-server, client-side

I'd like to start using clickstream analysis to improve a dynamic site's user experience. I'd like to rule out two options: parameterizing URLs (index.php?src=http://www.example.com) and immediate database logging. The former makes pretty ugly URLs and isn't great for SEO and the latter might slow down page render when there are lots of concurrent users.

Assuming these aren't viable options, I think I'm left with doing an asynchronous POST to a server side script that runs a database query and returns a 204 (no data) response. Is this the best option for capturing clickstream data?

Answer (score 7):

The following are some common ways to capture clickstream data

1. Use an analytics tool like [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/), [Amplitude](https://amplitude.com/), [MixPanel](https://mixpanel.com/) or [Heap](https://heap.io/). They make it really easy to capture the data, you don’t have to think about managing infrastructure, etc and they provide nice product analytics UI. They are perfect if product analytics is your eventual goal. The downside is that they can get pretty expensive once you cross their free tier. Another issue is that your data is locked with them and they charge extra to give you a dump. Increasingly, there are security & privacy issues with sharing data outside their control.
2. The other extreme option is Do-It-Yourself. Write a thin javascript library to capture click events, set up AWS Lambda or something to expose an API, dump the events into Kinesis and eventually to S3 or wherever you want. This is doable if you have a good engineering team. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/kinesis-examples.html) is a reference architecture from AWS.
3. The middle ground is to use a tool like [Segment](https://segment.com/), [RudderStack](https://rudderstack.com/) or [SnowPlow Analytics](https://snowplowanalytics.com/). They provide the client-side SDKs to capture the events and BE to collect/store the events wherever you want, e.g. your S3 or Redshift. Segment is a SaaS vendor while RudderStack is an open-source product but provides a hosted offering. Segment prices by users while RudderStack prices by nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rudimentary clickstream tracking using [Piwik](http://piwik.org) with the Live plugin.